# Not able to access FeedAttachment in afterInsert trigger

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I'm not able to access the FeedAttachment in afterInsert trigger on the FeedItem.

```
trigger FeedItemSizeCurve on FeedItem (after insert) {

    //Collect all ParentIds    
    for(FeedItem i : trigger.New){
        if(i.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Contact.SobjectType){
            List<FeedAttachment> attachments =  [SELECT Id, Title, Type, FeedEntityId 
                                                 FROM FeedAttachment 
                                                 WHERE FeedEntityId IN :Trigger.new ];
            System.debug('## attachments ##' + attachments);

            for (FeedAttachment attachment : attachments) {
                System.debug('## attachment.Type ##' + attachment.Type);
            }                     
        }
    }       
}
```

Many Thanks for support

Comment: How would a `FeedItem` have child records already in your `after insert` trigger? It just got created, it can't have any child records. Unless one of your other `after insert` triggers inserts them, and you can't depend on the order of trigger execution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you need to get the file content from the chatter post you shouldn't be using feedAttachment. Users could have either selected a file that has already been uploaded to files to be included in their chatter post or uploaded one. You can access the file either from the ContentData blob field, or accessing the ContentDocument and ContentVersion objects.